# How to read a remote image file from aws lambda and return that image file as a response

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to read a file which is in a remote location. Let's say https://abc/image.jpeg or https://abc/image.png. And I need to read this file and send it back as a response from a lambda function. One solution in NodeJS express is to use `res.sendFile` but I am not sure whether I can use it in a lambda and how to do that.

Another alternative is first copy image to a s3 bucket and then send it back. Any suggestions those are better than s3 copy option ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) and API Gateway `isBase64Encoded` option.

First, request the image and convert it to base64, using Buffer:

```
const imageBase64 = await axios.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
  .then(response => Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64'));
```

Next, return it from your lambda through API Gateway:

```
return {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: imageBase64,
  isBase64Encoded: true, //the most important part
}
```

However, keep in mind that API Gateway allows up to 10 megabytes of payload size. You'll get an error if your images are bigger.

Answer (score 1):

With request and express :

```
 var request = require("request");
 request.get('https://www.example.com/static/img/logo-light.png').pipe(res);
```